# Write down the probability mass function of $N$ and apply it to get $P[N = 2]$

Tags: probability, random-variables

A box has one white ball, $2$ black balls and $3$ grey balls. Balls are drawn one by one
and with replacement from the box. Let $N$ be the number of draws until all colors have
been observed (after any $2$ colors have been seen, we keep trying until the first time the
third color is seen).

Write down the probability mass function of $N$ and apply it to get $P[N = 2]$.

My attempt:

The last ball must be of a third color. So three cases arise:

$1-$ $(W$ or $B)$ in first $(N-1)$ draws and $G$ in $N$th draw.

$2-$ $(B$ or $G)$ in first $(N-1)$ draws and $W$ in $N$th draw.

$3-$ $(G$ or $W)$ in first $(N-1)$ draws and $B$ in $N$th draw.

I'll call these $P(1), P(2)$ and $P(3)$ respectively.

Then $P(1)=(1/6+1/3)^{(n-1)} *1/2$.

Similarly, $P(2)=(1/3+1/2)^{(n-1)} *1/6$ and

$P(3)=(1/2+1/6)^{(n-1)}*1/3$.

Summing them up gives us the required value for $P(N=n)$

However, when I try it for $P(N=2)$, I get $0.61$, which is wrong, because $P(N=2)$ should be $0$ as we cannot get $3$ different colors in $2$ draws.

Can someone please point out where I went wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Your notation isn't great...since $P(1)$, etc., depends on $n$ the notation should feature an $n$.  Maybe $P_1(n)$?

Comment: Also:  If I understand your calculation for $P_1(n)$, you are including those events of the form $W^{n-1}G$ which is not what you intend (I think).  You want *both* $W,B$ to appear in those first $n-1$ draws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the first case where you want only $W$ and $B$ in the first $(n-1)$ draws and then $G$ in the last draw.

$\small \displaystyle P(W) = \frac{1}{6}, P(B) = \frac{1}{3}, P(G) = \frac{1}{2}$.

$\small (1- P(G))^{n-1}$ will give you probability of only black or white in first $(n-1)$ draws but you need to subtracts two cases where all $(n-1)$ draws are either black or white.

So the probability should be $P_G(n) = \displaystyle \big(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} - \frac{1}{3^{n-1}} - \frac{1}{6^{n-1}}\big) \cdot \frac{1}{2}$

Now similarly find probability where the last drawn ball is $W$ and $B$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: So $P_W(n) = (\frac{1}{6^{n-1}} - \frac{1}{3^{n-1}} - \frac{1}{2^{n-1}})×1/6$ and $P_B(n) = (\frac{1}{3^{n-1}} - \frac{1}{6^{n-1}} - \frac{1}{2^{n-1}})×1/3$?

Comment: The first term is wrong in both. $(1-P(W)) = 5/6$ and $(1-P(B)) = 2/3$ so $(5/6)^{n-1}$ and $(2/3)^{n-1}$ resp. Rest seems fine.